# GMP Library for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a GMP Library that is used for BIG integer calculation in C++.
I am unable to compile the same in Xcode for iOS development.
Please Provide with details steps regarding how to compile GMP for iOS Development

Comment: You will need to give more info. Show the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GenieWanted said, provide more information!!!

However, I compiled successfully the GMP library for iOS 7 64 bits following the next step:

> ./configure
>   CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang"
>   CPP="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -E" CPPFLAGS="-target arm64-apple-darwin -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/
>   -miphoneos-version-min=7.0" --host=aarch64-apple-darwin --disable-assembly --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=/your-path/

I would like to point out that it only creates the C library, I do not think is different for C++, however I will try this afternoon.

Comment: Please share with me the details steps you followed to build it for iOS Platform.
Also share the tar file link from where you downloaded the Gmp tar.bz and the necessary scripts with proper steps that should be followed to get it run for iOS Application

Comment: I followed steps as follows
Download and extract the gmp4osx project

Open up and edit gmp4osx-master/libgmp/gmp4osx

On line 19 it says IOSVERSION=5.1, change it to IOSVERSION=6.1

Save the file

Browse to that directory with terminal and type in ./gmp4osx -b

But during the make command it said unable to locate directory.

Comment: I used one of the latest version of gmp (6.0.0a) which can be found at https://gmplib.org/download/snapshot/. By the way do not install the new developer tools of iOS 8 which will be released today, maybe you cannot use the gmp on them. As well, I used the gmp4osx but I think it is not longer available to work properly, do not use it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and help.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I realize that there has been some considerable time gone by but none of the information in the previous answer worked for me.  Here is how I was able to do it, hope this helps someone else in the future.

1. Grab the gmp snapshot from https://gmplib.org/download/snapshot/
2. It is in .lz format, it will need to be uncompressed.  if you have a mac, uncompress it using lzip, install with homebrew  `brew install lzip`
3. Once its uncompressed from lzip, then it will be a .tar file, the finder can take care of that for you.  You will have a gmp folder with a bunch of files and other sub-folders.

You will need Xcode commandline tools installed.  Make sure you have that pre-installed.

Run this configure line.  Take care to note that you need to put in your path to the directory you want it to be stored, in `--prefix`.

```
./configure CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -fembed-bitcode -arch arm64e --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk" CPPFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode -arch arm64e --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk " --disable-shared --enable-static --host=arm-apple-darwin --disable-assembly --prefix="{ YOUR_PATH_HERE }/GMP_6_1_99/gmp-6.1.99-20200117/gmplib-iphoneos-arm64e"
```

Then you run (notice the same path as before for the log files)

```
make -j  &> "{ YOUR_PATH_HERE }/gmp-6.1.99-20200117/gmplib-iphoneos-arm64e-build.log"

make install &> "{ YOUR_PATH_HERE }/gmp-6.1.99-20200117/gmplib-iphoneos-arm64e-install.log"
```

There are two main points to those lines that are changeable, the platform, and the architecture.  The above uses the `arm64e` architecture but you can just as easily build for `arm64, armv7, armv7s`.  Also you can change out the platform as well and build for `macosx, watchos, iphonesimulator, or appletvos`.  To change the platform you need to find the sdk of where it lives on your machine.  The other architecture options are `x86_64 i386`,   To do that, type this into your terminal...

```
xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
(replace "iphoneos" with the platform you are looking to use from above)
```

And replace the SDK path.  Make sure you match with the correct architecture or else you will get an error, `cannot find compiler`.

Comment: I followed all the instructions but I get an error: could not find a working compiler... I set the prefix (custom path), platform (iPhoneOS14.4.sdk) and architecture (arm64) ... [repository](github.com/quaternionboy/GMP-iOS)

Answer (score 0):

[@bolnad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664368/bolnad)'s answer worked for me doing a small modification, removing the `-fembed-bitcode` flag both from CC and CPPFLAGS.

EDIT: it ended up not correctly compiling the different architectures, so I found this script on github https://github.com/FlowCrypt/GMP and was able to build correctly.